# How can i change the classes generated by styled components in react?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

The classes generated by styled components are : sc-igwadP, Is there any way I can customize it to be something like that? => Icon_sc-igwadP

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with a Babel plugin: [babel-plugin-styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components).

One of the default options from this plugin makes CSS classes easier to identify:

> Better debugging: This option enhances the attached CSS class name on each component with richer output to help identify your components in the DOM without React DevTools. In your page source you'll see: `<button class="Button-asdf123 asdf123" />` instead of just `<button class="asdf123" />`.

[More info here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work following the official instruction. Anyone got a working repo?